# java и XDTO пакет

Tags: java, android, 1с, soap

Есть мобильное приложение на android с одной стороны и веб-сервис от 1с с другой стороны. Уже реализована передача данных из 1с в приложение. Но теперь возник вопрос, нужно передавать данные из приложения в 1с, я могу передать число или какой-то другой примитивный тип данных, но в данном случае нужно передать XDTO пакет. 
Вот собственно процедура из 1с которая обработает переданный пакет:

```
Процедура getOrder(Order, Manager)

        ТекстХМЛ = Новый ЧтениеXML; 
        ТекстХМЛ.УстановитьСтроку(Order.Получить());
        ТипЗаказы= ФабрикаXDTO.Тип("http://www.livsig.org","Заказы");
        Заказы = ФабрикаXDTO.ПрочитатьXML(ТекстХМЛ, ТипЗаказы); 
        ТекстХМЛ.Закрыть(); 

        СоздатьПринятыеЗакаы(Заказы.СписокЗаказов,Manager);

КонецПроцедуры
```

Как мне на стороне android приложения получить нужный мне тип XDTO, с помощью него сформировать пакет и отдать его веб сервису? 
Это вообще реально? Вот пример того, как я передаю на сервер строку:

```
request = new SoapObject(StandartSetting.NAMESPACE_F2,StandartSetting.SEND_F2_ORDERS);
request.addProperty("Order",null);
request.addProperty("Manager", settingsHelper.getSettingsValue(StandartSetting.F2_MANAGER_NAME));

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportBasicAuthSE("http://"+settingsHelper.getSettingsValue(StandartSetting.DB_ADRESS)+StandartSetting.URL_F2,settingsHelper.getSettingsValue(StandartSetting.F2_MANAGER_NAME),"");  HttpTransport.call("http://"+settingsHelper.getSettingsValue(StandartSetting.DB_ADRESS)+StandartSetting.SOAP_ACTION_F2_ORDERS, envelope);
envelope.getResponse();
```

P.s с веб-сервисами работаю с помощью библиотеки ksoap2

Comment: Я бы шел таким путем: в 1С попробовал бы сформировать xml-файл содержащий Order с помощью (Новый ЗаписьXML) Из этого xml-файла убрал лишние поля; И далее генерировал этот файл из Андроида как текст (без обращения к XDTO).

Comment: @santavital, что делать с GUID объекта? Лучше попробовать утилиту wsimport из jdk и посмотреть как будет выглядеть. Я работаю с сервисами 1С именно так, с помощью wsimport генерю классы и использую их для работы с сервисами

Comment: Решил проблему строками, т.е. собираю данные в строку с разделителем, а на стороне сервиса её парсят в массив, слезки текут, когда смотрю на эту реализацию :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще будет на стороне приложения собрать данные в JSON объект, потом его строкой передать в 1с. 1С хорошо работает с JSON, не нужно будет парсить строки и тп.
В 1С это выглядит примерно так:

```
ТелоЗапроса = Запрос.ПолучитьТелоКакСтроку(КодировкаТекста.UTF8);
ЧтениеДанных = Новый ЧтениеJSON;
ЧтениеДанных.УстановитьСтроку(ТелоЗапроса);
ДанныеДокумента  = ПрочитатьJSON(ЧтениеДанных);
ЧтениеДанных.Закрыть();
```

Теперь в переменной ДанныеДокумента будет Структура с полями из JSON-а, читаем свойства, пишем в базу. Как-то так.

Comment: Спасибо, хорошее решение!